# Why is it taking so long until rx.interval creates any output?

Tags: python, reactive, rx-py

I wanted to create an observable that emits an event at an interval of 100 ms.

I tried using `rx.interval`:

```
import rx
tick = rx.interval(100)
tick.subscribe(on_next=lambda i: print(i))
```

The process is not running and gives the disposable as output:

```
<rx.disposable.disposable.Disposable object at 0x7f7eac712dd8>
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Interval is in seconds. So this works fine:

```
rx.interval(0.1).subscribe(on_next=lambda i: print(i))
```